# How to compare matrix elements to threshold in NumPy

Tags: numpy, matrix, comparison

I have a matrix of positive values, as well as a list of thresholds. The list of thresholds is sorted. For example:

```
X = np.matrix([[1., 2., 3.,], [0., 2., 1.], [4., 1., 2.]])
y = [0.5, 1., 3., 5.]
```

I would like to write a function that sets all entries of X that are smaller than y[1] to y[1], all entries that are equal to or greater than y[1] and smaller than y[2] to y[2], etc.

This can be done by simply iterating over the matrix entries and thresholds, of course, but I would like to find a more efficient way. I've looked at `clip`, but it does not quite do what I need it to.

Comment: can you explain what you want to say by  "all entries of X that are smaller than y[1] to y[1], all entries that are equal to or greater than y[1] and smaller than y[2] to y[2], etc." thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to obtain the indices:

```
>>> np.array(y)[np.searchsorted(y, X)]
array([[ 1. ,  3. ,  3. ],
       [ 0.5,  3. ,  1. ],
       [ 5. ,  1. ,  3. ]])
```